# Python dictionary initialization and values append to list

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Question: Write function that for a given list of objects, returns a dictionary of type: [object].
For example: `func([1,2.0,3,'g']) returns: {'i':[1,3], 'f': [2.0], 'c': ['g'], 'o': []}`

- key `i` for ints
- key `f` for floats
- key `c` for chars
- key `o` for others

My code:

```
def make_dict(lst):
    my_dict = {'i': [], 'f': [], 'c': [], 'o': []}
    [my_dict['i'].append(item) if isinstance(item, int) else my_dict['f'].append(item) if isinstance(
        item, float) else my_dict['c'].append(item) if isinstance(item, str) and len(item) == 1 else my_dict['o'].append(item) for item in lst]
    return my_dict
```

This function returning the corrent dictionary, but I need to make it a One-Liner, plus, I don't like the way it's done. I know the use of list comprehension is bad here.

My though process was to first make this a multiple lines function, which i did using for loops and if elif statements, Then i tried to combine those lines and eventually got it down to 3.

This is the for loop i used before combining it into a list comprehenson:

```
for item in lst:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        my_dict['i'].append(item)
    elif isinstance(item, float):
        my_dict['f'].append(item)
    elif isinstance(item, str) and len(item) == 1:
        my_dict['c'].append(item)
    else:
        my_dict['o'].append(item)
return my_dict
```

My problem:
I know i need to use some sort of Dictionary comprehension combined with map() of filter() in some way, but after searching the internet and finding noting.. I just don't know how to do it.

Maybe you can help me? THANKS!

Comment: What did you code into a list comprehension ? As you don't keep it, use a loo^p

Comment: I did list comprehension because my goal is to make it a One-liner. The first thing i did was to solve it with for loop and if elif statements, then i tried to combine all those into one list comprehenson line.

Comment: Share the if/else code, it would easier to understand first. Also you did not explain the purpose, we have to figured it out by ourself an explanation would have been nice

Comment: Why do you want a one-liner? Use multiple statements. It makes the code easier to write and read.

Comment: Besides, if you want a one liner, you cannot use list-comprehension. You'd need to use the equivalent for a dict. Also, `append` is a method with side-effects, which usually makes it quit inconvenient and much harder to use generators.

Comment: I editied the code. added some explanation about the dictionary and the for loop code. The goal is to make this in a single line (return ....). I know i should use dictionary domprehenson instand of list, but I cant find the corrent way to do it. What should I use instand of append? I need to add item to the list if it matches type.

Comment: You need to create the list directly; you cannot append one item at a time. Which is why this is difficult to do. You have an answer below that seems to work, but I'd still strongly suggest using the code you have in your second snippet, even if it's not a one-liner. Well, it is actually a one-liner if you put it in a function, as everywhere you call it will look like `my_dict = make_dict(lst)`. Most one-liners are achieved by calling other built-in functions, but there is no difference between that and calling your one functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to group the data by the first letter of their type so

- get the first letter of their type `type(x).__name__[0]`
- group the data by this criteria

You need to provide data to `groupby` sorted by the same criteria you'll use for the grouping. the `{k:list(v)` part is to move from a `groupby` object to a `dict`

```
from itertools import groupby

def make_dict(lst):
    sorter = lambda x:type(x).__name__[0] if type(x).__name__ in ('int', 'float', 'str') else 'o'
    return {k:list(v) for k,v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=sorter), key=sorter)}

r = make_dict([1,2.0,3,'g']) # {'f': [2.0], 'i': [1, 3], 's': ['g']}
print(r)
```

---

Using `filter`, but not efficient as you iterate the list multiple times

```
def make_dict(lst):
    return {'i': list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(item, int), lst)), 
            'f': list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(item, float), lst)), 
            's': list(filter(lambda x: isinstance(item, str), lst)), 
            'o': type(x).__name__ not in ('int', 'float', 'str')}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is progress but I did not explained the format good in the first place, the criteria should be: 'i' for ints, 'f' for floats, 'c' for chars, and 'o' for other. Is there a way to use a map function instand? In my head this was the "right" way to make it and I tried converting the "bad" list comprehenson i had into a map function. (We learned map, filter and reduce function in class and not groupby.) You think this is possible or the groupby is the best way? THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: @Birkagal You can change the lambda to `lambda x: type(x).__name__[0] if type(x).__name__ in ('int', 'float', 'str') else 'o'`.

Comment: @Birkagal the map operation is to tranform a data to another, this is not what we want to do here, use a loop loke the other answer, or groupby, ('ve add the default other)

Comment: @azro yeah that map problem is what i've encountered (fact it's making new one and not changing the original dictionary) is there a way to use filter then? Because to be honest the question said: "use map/reduce/filter and lambda expression to create one line function that does ...." that's why im trying to figure out a way to do it with the stuff learned in class.

Comment: @Birkagal i've proposed a solution with filter, that's my final word on that

Comment: @azro Thank you. I understand going 4 times is not ideal. I find it werid there is no way to loop in this list and map each object to hes corrent spot in the dictionary.. That was my first intuition. The solution you gave is using stuff we learn so I guess it's good enough for my teacher. Thank you again sir for helping out with this one I know i did not explain my problem the best at the beginning but thats for sticking through!